# how to start draw line from X - Y axis at o in JFreeChart ChartFactory.createLineChart

Tags: java, swing, jfreechart

i am creating line chart using `JFreeChart`.

Line chart draw properly but i want to start at point 0. how can i do that?

```
public void lineChart()
{
         CategoryDataset ds=createDataset2();
         chart2=ChartFactory.createLineChart("Bar Chart", "OPD Number", "Weight", ds,PlotOrientation.VERTICAL,true,true,false);

         ChartPanel cp = new ChartPanel(chart2);
         jp.add(cp);                     //jp is JPanel 
    }
    public CategoryDataset createDataset2() 
    {
        final DefaultCategoryDataset dataset= new DefaultCategoryDataset();
        final String series1 = "Type1";
        OPDDetailBean ob=new OPDDetailBean();
        ArrayList<OPDDetailBean> aob=new ArrayList<OPDDetailBean>();
        aob=ob.searchOPDDetails("5");
        for(int i=0;i<aob.size();i++)
        {
            dataset.addValue(Integer.parseInt(aob.get(i).getWeight()), series1, ""+(i+1));    
        }
        return dataset;
    }
```

which give output..

[image]

And i want output like.

[image]

Comment: Image display title "Bar Chart" .... sorry its "Line Chart"

Comment: dataset.addValue(Integer.parseInt(aob.get(i).getWeight()), series1, ""+(i+1)); <--- Why do you use (i+1) as column value?

Comment: I'm skimming through the demos, and I don't see any examples where your desired output occurs. Though I see it achieved using `XYPLot`

Comment: Question is, why would you want to do that? Does that line represent actual data starting at 0.

Comment: Hello StanislavL, i use (i+1) to display OPD Number at X axis;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"1", "2", "3", "4" and "5" are categories in your example. You don't have a category "0", so there cannot be a line to it. Either add a category "0" and adapt the axis-margin if you want 0 to be on the left border of the plot. Or probably better: use an XYPlot and corresponding methodes from ChartFactory like [`createXYLineChart()`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/ChartFactory.html#createXYLineChart%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20org.jfree.data.xy.XYDataset%29).

hth,
- martin