# How to create Line Chart that starts from zero and 1 axis must be string-based?

Tags: java, jsp, jfreechart, linechart

My question is a combination of these old questions.

[how to start draw line from X - Y axis at o in JFreeChart ChartFactory.createLineChart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20604462/how-to-start-draw-line-from-x-y-axis-at-o-in-jfreechart-chartfactory-createlin)

[How to draw line chart using jfreechart from top to bottom?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25993430/how-to-draw-line-chart-using-jfreechart-from-top-to-bottom)

I'm working in a project and need to implement a feature to create a line chart using JFreechart. Each line chart must satisfy all 2 conditions.

- Each line must start from (0,0) coordinate (or at least look like that)
- X-axis must be string-based. For example: "30-Oct-2017", "04-Dec-2017", etc.

**EDITED:** ok I decided to implement TimeSeriesCollection as the chart's dataset. This is what I have so far.

```
private String makeLineChart(Map<Date, List<Map<String, Object>>> entryMap, String type, PlotOrientation chartOrientation)
{
    String newline = System.getProperty("line.separator");
    int maxNumberOfResponses = 0;
    JFreeChart chart;
    List<Date> listEntryMapKeys = new ArrayList<Date>(entryMap.keySet());

    switch (type)
    {
        case "line":
        default:

            DefaultCategoryDataset resultLine = new DefaultCategoryDataset();

            TimeSeriesCollection dataset = new TimeSeriesCollection();
            List<TimeSeries> listOfSeries = new ArrayList<TimeSeries>();
            List<String> titles = new ArrayList<String>();                              
            Date startSurveyDate = listEntryMapKeys.get(0);
            Date endSurveyDate = listEntryMapKeys.get(listEntryMapKeys.size() - 1);
            StringBuilder sblog = new StringBuilder();
            String logtitle = "";
            String logfilename = String.format("Debug_makeLineChart_SurveyAnalyticsController");

            for (int i = 0; i < listEntryMapKeys.size(); i++)
            {
                Date d = listEntryMapKeys.get(i);
                Date pd = (i >= 1) ? listEntryMapKeys.get(i - 1) : d;
                String date = DateTimeConverter.ParseDateToString(d, Chart.CHART_DATE_FORMAT);//for either x or y column
                String prevdate = DateTimeConverter.ParseDateToString(pd, Chart.CHART_DATE_FORMAT);

                List<Map<String, Object>> listOfStatistics = entryMap.get(d);

                Map<String, Integer> mapOfStatisticsByQuestionResult = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
                for (Map<String, Object> subEntity : listOfStatistics)
                {
                    String title = subEntity.get("qrtitle").toString().trim();

                    if (!mapOfStatisticsByQuestionResult.containsKey(title))
                    {
                        mapOfStatisticsByQuestionResult.put(title, 1);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        int count = mapOfStatisticsByQuestionResult.get(title) + 1;
                        mapOfStatisticsByQuestionResult.put(title, count);
                    }
                }

                sblog.append("Debugging date ");
                sblog.append((new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy")).format(d));
                sblog.append("...");
                sblog.append(newline);
                sblog.append("Value of mapOfStatisticsByQuestionResult:");
                sblog.append(StringConverter.ParseObjectToJson(mapOfStatisticsByQuestionResult));
                sblog.append(newline);
                for (int k = 0; k < 5; k++)
                {
                    sblog.append("-");
                }
                sblog.append(newline);

                for (String result : mapOfStatisticsByQuestionResult.keySet())
                {
                    int count = mapOfStatisticsByQuestionResult.get(result);//should be the sum of current & previous
                    TimeSeries series = new TimeSeries(result);

                    sblog.append(newline);
                    sblog.append("Searching for item with key is ");
                    sblog.append(result);
                    sblog.append(" in listOfSeries (");
                    sblog.append(listOfSeries.size());
                    sblog.append(" item(s))...");
                    sblog.append(newline);

                    TimeSeries currentSeries = listOfSeries.stream().filter(x -> x.getKey() != null && x.getKey().toString().trim().equalsIgnoreCase(result)).findFirst().orElse(null);
                    sblog.append(currentSeries != null ? "NOT FOUND" : "FOUND");
                    sblog.append(newline);

                    int indexOfSeries = IntStream.range(0, listOfSeries.size()).
                            filter(x -> listOfSeries.get(x).getKey() != null && listOfSeries.get(x).getKey().toString().trim().equalsIgnoreCase(result)).
                            findFirst().orElse(-1);

                    sblog.append("Index of the item: ");
                    sblog.append(indexOfSeries);
                    sblog.append(newline);
                    sblog.append(newline);

                    if (indexOfSeries >= 0)
                    {
                        series = listOfSeries.get(indexOfSeries);
                    }

                    if (!titles.contains(date))
                    {
                        titles.add(date);
                    }

                    if (i >= 1)
                    {
                        if (chartOrientation == PlotOrientation.HORIZONTAL)
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                int current = resultLine.getValue(result, prevdate).intValue();
                                int sum = current + count;
                                resultLine.addValue(sum, result, date);
                                series.addOrUpdate(new Day(d), count); //series.addOrUpdate(new Day(d), sum);                                    

                                if (sum > maxNumberOfResponses)
                                {
                                    maxNumberOfResponses = sum;
                                }
                            }
                            catch (Exception ex)
                            {
                                //resultLine.addValue(0, result, "0");
                                resultLine.addValue(count, result, date);
                                series.addOrUpdate(new Day(d), count);

                                if (count > maxNumberOfResponses)
                                {
                                    maxNumberOfResponses = count;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                int current = resultLine.getValue(prevdate, result).intValue();
                                int sum = current + count;
                                resultLine.addValue(sum, date, result);
                                series.addOrUpdate(new Day(d), count); //series.addOrUpdate(new Day(d), sum);

                                if (sum > maxNumberOfResponses)
                                {
                                    maxNumberOfResponses = sum;
                                }
                            }
                            catch (Exception ex)
                            {
                                //resultLine.addValue(0, result, "0");
                                resultLine.addValue(count, date, result);
                                series.addOrUpdate(new Day(d), count);

                                if (count > maxNumberOfResponses)
                                {
                                    maxNumberOfResponses = count;
                                }
                            }
                        }

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //resultLine.addValue(0, result, "0");
                        if (chartOrientation == PlotOrientation.HORIZONTAL)
                        {
                            resultLine.addValue(count, result, date);
                            series.addOrUpdate(new Day(d), count);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            resultLine.addValue(count, date, result);
                            series.addOrUpdate(new Day(d), count);
                        }

                        if (count > maxNumberOfResponses)
                        {
                            maxNumberOfResponses = count;
                        }

                    }

                    indexOfSeries = IntStream.range(0, listOfSeries.size()).
                            filter(x -> listOfSeries.get(x).getKey() != null && listOfSeries.get(x).getKey().toString().trim().equalsIgnoreCase(result)).
                            findFirst().orElse(-1);//suspicious of giving wrong result

                    sblog.append("Index of the item (before adding new item): ");
                    sblog.append(indexOfSeries);
                    sblog.append(newline);

                    if (indexOfSeries >= 0)
                    {
                        listOfSeries.set(indexOfSeries, series);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        listOfSeries.add(series);
                    }
                }

            }

            sblog.append(newline);
            for (int k = 0; k < 20; k++)
            {
                sblog.append("-");
            }
            sblog.append(newline);
            sblog.append("Debugging listOfSeries (");
            sblog.append(listOfSeries.size());
            sblog.append(" item(s))...");
            sblog.append(newline);
            for (int k = 0; k < 10; k++)
            {
                sblog.append("-");
            }

            SimpleDateFormat dateformatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");

            int index = 0;
            for (TimeSeries series : listOfSeries)
            {
                index++;

                if (series.getTimePeriod(0).getStart().after(startSurveyDate))
                {
                    series.addOrUpdate(new Day(startSurveyDate), 0);
                }
                else if (series.getValue(0).doubleValue() > 0)
                {
                    series.addOrUpdate(new Day(DateTimeConverter.AddOrSubtractDay(startSurveyDate, -1)), 0);
                }

                if (series.getTimePeriod(series.getItemCount() - 1).getEnd().before(endSurveyDate))
                {
                    series.addOrUpdate(new Day(endSurveyDate), 0);
                }
                else if (series.getValue(series.getItemCount() - 1).doubleValue() > 0)
                {
                    series.addOrUpdate(new Day(DateTimeConverter.AddOrSubtractDay(endSurveyDate, 1)), 0);
                }

                dataset.addSeries(series);

                sblog.append(newline);
                sblog.append("Debugging series ");
                sblog.append(index);
                sblog.append("...");
                sblog.append(newline);
                sblog.append("Title: ");
                sblog.append("\"");
                sblog.append(series.getKey().toString());
                sblog.append("\"");
                sblog.append(newline);

                for (int i = 0; i < series.getItemCount(); i++)
                {
                    sblog.append("Time period: ");
                    sblog.append(dateformatter.format(series.getTimePeriod(i).getStart()));
                    sblog.append(" - ");
                    sblog.append(dateformatter.format(series.getTimePeriod(i).getEnd()));
                    sblog.append(newline);
                    sblog.append("Value: ");
                    sblog.append("\"");
                    sblog.append(series.getValue(series.getTimePeriod(i)));
                    sblog.append("\"");
                    sblog.append(" ");
                    sblog.append("(");
                    sblog.append(series.getValue(i));
                    sblog.append(")");
                    sblog.append(newline);
                }

                sblog.append(newline);
                sblog.append(newline);
            }

            sblog.append(newline);

            String logcontent = sblog.toString();
            DebugWriter.WriteLogToFile(logtitle, logcontent, logfilename, false);

            if (chartOrientation == PlotOrientation.HORIZONTAL)
            {
                chart = ChartFactory.createXYLineChart("", "Number of responses", "Number of responses", dataset, PlotOrientation.HORIZONTAL, true, true, false);
            }
            else
            {
                chart = ChartFactory.createXYLineChart("", "Survey date", "Number of responses", dataset, PlotOrientation.VERTICAL, true, true, false);
            }

            XYPlot plot = (XYPlot) chart.getPlot();
            DateAxis dateAxis = new DateAxis("Survey dates");
            dateAxis.setLabelFont(new Font(Font.SERIF, Font.BOLD, 20));
            dateAxis.setDateFormatOverride(new SimpleDateFormat(Chart.CHART_DATE_FORMAT));
            if (chartOrientation == PlotOrientation.HORIZONTAL)
            {
                dateAxis.setInverted(true);
            }
            dateAxis.setMinimumDate(startSurveyDate);
            dateAxis.setMaximumDate(endSurveyDate);
            dateAxis.setLowerBound(0);
            dateAxis.setAutoRange(true);
            plot.setDomainAxis(dateAxis);

            NumberAxis numberAxis = (NumberAxis) plot.getRangeAxis();
            numberAxis.setAutoRange(true);
            plot.setRangeAxis(numberAxis);

            break;
    }

    String code = UUID.randomUUID().toString().replaceAll("-", "");
    String filename = new File(chartDir, code + ".png").getAbsolutePath();

    try
    {
        File tmpdir = new File(chartDir);
        if (!tmpdir.exists())
        {                
            tmpdir.mkdirs();
        }

        if (maxNumberOfResponses < 20)
        {
            maxNumberOfResponses = chartOrientation == PlotOrientation.HORIZONTAL ? maxNumberOfResponses * 50 : maxNumberOfResponses * 15;
        }
        else if (maxNumberOfResponses < 50)
        {
            maxNumberOfResponses = chartOrientation == PlotOrientation.HORIZONTAL ? maxNumberOfResponses * 45 : maxNumberOfResponses * 10;
        }
        else if (maxNumberOfResponses < 100)
        {
            maxNumberOfResponses = chartOrientation == PlotOrientation.HORIZONTAL ? maxNumberOfResponses * 40 : maxNumberOfResponses * 5;
        }
        else
        {
            maxNumberOfResponses = chartOrientation == PlotOrientation.HORIZONTAL ? maxNumberOfResponses * 30 : maxNumberOfResponses;
        }

        int sizeRangeAxis = (maxNumberOfResponses >= 1) ? (chartOrientation == PlotOrientation.HORIZONTAL ? 300 + maxNumberOfResponses : 200 + maxNumberOfResponses) : 200 + (entryMap.size() - 1) * 50;
        int sizeDomainAxis = chartOrientation == PlotOrientation.HORIZONTAL ? 200 + listEntryMapKeys.size() * 70 : 200 + listEntryMapKeys.size() * 100;
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(filename);

        if (chartOrientation == PlotOrientation.HORIZONTAL)
        {
            ChartUtilities.writeChartAsPNG(fos, chart, sizeRangeAxis, sizeDomainAxis);
        }
        else
        {
            ChartUtilities.writeChartAsPNG(fos, chart, sizeDomainAxis, sizeRangeAxis);
        }

        fos.close();

        return "/survey-analytics.yo?chart=yes&code=" + code;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {

    }

    return "";
}
```

This is my sample data.

```
{
    "Wed Aug 09 00:00:00 ICT 2017": [],
    "Tue Aug 15 00:00:00 ICT 2017": [],
    "Wed Aug 16 00:00:00 ICT 2017": [],
    "Fri Aug 25 00:00:00 ICT 2017": [],
    "Mon Oct 16 00:00:00 ICT 2017": [{
            "qrid": "6a3560a320ca4ae89e6475f81bd439b36a3560a320ca4ae89e6475f81bd439b3.ac432e0f4b1349aa90307dbf4d4a26fa",
            "qrtitle": "Iphone 8s plus is better.",
            "qid": "269c2de5d3634800a36d64e342b24cba",
            "qkind": "ranking",
            "srid": "ec11d1f285db4350bad7176db1cb94db"
        },
        {
            "qrid": "6a3560a320ca4ae89e6475f81bd439b36a3560a320ca4ae89e6475f81bd439b3.c114317c90f148a38748afb725ab3081",
            "qrtitle": "Iphone 8s plus is better.",
            "qid": "269c2de5d3634800a36d64e342b24cba",
            "qkind": "ranking",
            "srid": "4a97a0bb8bc14c6ba79f1fa7546fb931"
        },
        {
            "qrid": "6a3560a320ca4ae89e6475f81bd439b36a3560a320ca4ae89e6475f81bd439b3.dc5308e8a6bf40b0b9bbb7f036b7539b",
            "qrtitle": "Iphone 8s plus is better.",
            "qid": "269c2de5d3634800a36d64e342b24cba",
            "qkind": "ranking",
            "srid": "eaad14795e6847698faa8c6ebba4f60f"
        },
        {
            "qrid": "5d7f9cc459bf4ee8a805c9fccaeabb405d7f9cc459bf4ee8a805c9fccaeabb40.eb751643f52442fb8565a8f4ef486518",
            "qrtitle": "this is the one i like.",
            "qid": "269c2de5d3634800a36d64e342b24cba",
            "qkind": "ranking",
            "srid": "e71924f9a8554820a27f891af019ad0c"
        },
        {
            "qrid": "263c99a0687b4628a042f2908cda6c83263c99a0687b4628a042f2908cda6c83.f0d34ce46f4d4312a903363482d03cb7",
            "qrtitle": "S9 is better.",
            "qid": "269c2de5d3634800a36d64e342b24cba",
            "qkind": "ranking",
            "srid": "b6fc0300b61647a29754433f87022674"
        },
        {
            "qrid": "263c99a0687b4628a042f2908cda6c83263c99a0687b4628a042f2908cda6c83.f1e0f921a4ec40038d2973cb34e10b00",
            "qrtitle": "S9 is better.",
            "qid": "269c2de5d3634800a36d64e342b24cba",
            "qkind": "ranking",
            "srid": "6c06cc1b4ed4460484963e6dcbf44db6"
        },
        {
            "qrid": "6a3560a320ca4ae89e6475f81bd439b36a3560a320ca4ae89e6475f81bd439b3.fd14094cc6b74c3995ce32796510ee14",
            "qrtitle": "Iphone 8s plus is better.",
            "qid": "269c2de5d3634800a36d64e342b24cba",
            "qkind": "ranking",
            "srid": "9c536e71e5604a63afdbb8c01bbd8745"
        },
        {
            "qrid": "6a3560a320ca4ae89e6475f81bd439b36a3560a320ca4ae89e6475f81bd439b3.ffef655a26284b539cf39b57249938ab",
            "qrtitle": "Iphone 8s plus is better.",
            "qid": "269c2de5d3634800a36d64e342b24cba",
            "qkind": "ranking",
            "srid": "00617cf9d537465aa02795571830100f"
        }
    ],
    "Thu Nov 30 00:00:00 ICT 2017": [{
            "qrid": "5d7f9cc459bf4ee8a805c9fccaeabb405d7f9cc459bf4ee8a805c9fccaeabb40.0f4fdf31a2904c87a588f22f71ddac12",
            "qrtitle": "this is the one i like.",
            "qid": "269c2de5d3634800a36d64e342b24cba",
            "qkind": "ranking",
            "srid": "2d90d38546e94e94b22190d03609312d"
        },
        {
            "qrid": "5d7f9cc459bf4ee8a805c9fccaeabb405d7f9cc459bf4ee8a805c9fccaeabb40.12049a8c710743418e2a0b6128599022",
            "qrtitle": "this is the one i like.",
            "qid": "269c2de5d3634800a36d64e342b24cba",
            "qkind": "ranking",
            "srid": "80e5669fe68d40b7b7bef3d54d1898a7"
        },
        {
            "qrid": "5d7f9cc459bf4ee8a805c9fccaeabb405d7f9cc459bf4ee8a805c9fccaeabb40.1c3de97497bc462b8193eb0b8218b9f3",
            "qrtitle": "this is the one i like.",
            "qid": "269c2de5d3634800a36d64e342b24cba",
            "qkind": "ranking",
            "srid": "5b1decddfbd34593aa6f2d8b0e8ca380"
        },
        {
            "qrid": "5d7f9cc459bf4ee8a805c9fccaeabb405d7f9cc459bf4ee8a805c9fccaeabb40.24d9c0c319d942b89249770429a68dfd",
            "qrtitle": "this is the one i like.",
            "qid": "269c2de5d3634800a36d64e342b24cba",
            "qkind": "ranking",
            "srid": "b0df84a9bee542a395df215403eacfad"
        },
        {
            "qrid": "5d7f9cc459bf4ee8a805c9fccaeabb405d7f9cc459bf4ee8a805c9fccaeabb40.2aad5178de414b41af0bbf9d5dda052a",
            "qrtitle": "this is the one i like.",
            "qid": "269c2de5d3634800a36d64e342b24cba",
            "qkind": "ranking",
            "srid": "798e5cd22888488fa7079fb607343690"
        },
        {
            "qrid": "5d7f9cc459bf4ee8a805c9fccaeabb405d7f9cc459bf4ee8a805c9fccaeabb40.467e5e10fb684063908b437a16b25ed3",
            "qrtitle": "this is the one i like.",
            "qid": "269c2de5d3634800a36d64e342b24cba",
            "qkind": "ranking",
            "srid": "69a7290bb366461bb44e911c8a19860a"
        },
        {
            "qrid": "5d7f9cc459bf4ee8a805c9fccaeabb405d7f9cc459bf4ee8a805c9fccaeabb40.55ca4e24035347f1ba26371bcc08fde0",
            "qrtitle": "this is the one i like.",
            "qid": "269c2de5d3634800a36d64e342b24cba",
            "qkind": "ranking",
            "srid": "d8915cf7aaa1403c949d5ec396294d76"
        },
        {
            "qrid": "5d7f9cc459bf4ee8a805c9fccaeabb405d7f9cc459bf4ee8a805c9fccaeabb40.68f62cf3e87c463aa43d503a0b79a998",
            "qrtitle": "this is the one i like.",
            "qid": "269c2de5d3634800a36d64e342b24cba",
            "qkind": "ranking",
            "srid": "2decfab381fe4f15a7fe2197be9aba6d"
        },
        {
            "qrid": "5d7f9cc459bf4ee8a805c9fccaeabb405d7f9cc459bf4ee8a805c9fccaeabb40.9000ee0cf4d6434e976bc02a5edeb78a",
            "qrtitle": "this is the one i like.",
            "qid": "269c2de5d3634800a36d64e342b24cba",
            "qkind": "ranking",
            "srid": "19b17bc0f11f47c1bcbd10bd84bde4c9"
        },
        {
            "qrid": "5d7f9cc459bf4ee8a805c9fccaeabb405d7f9cc459bf4ee8a805c9fccaeabb40.aee76445534f4594905e0be410b16434",
            "qrtitle": "this is the one i like.",
            "qid": "269c2de5d3634800a36d64e342b24cba",
            "qkind": "ranking",
            "srid": "938aae681b584e049210d508797fe5c2"
        },
        {
            "qrid": "5d7f9cc459bf4ee8a805c9fccaeabb405d7f9cc459bf4ee8a805c9fccaeabb40.ffd3a7f602e142e583dd4eb57cab042c",
            "qrtitle": "this is the one i like.",
            "qid": "269c2de5d3634800a36d64e342b24cba",
            "qkind": "ranking",
            "srid": "b63824a2a8a04422a9c9756ef56992c1"
        }
    ],
    "Mon Dec 04 00:00:00 ICT 2017": [{
            "qrid": "5d7f9cc459bf4ee8a805c9fccaeabb405d7f9cc459bf4ee8a805c9fccaeabb40.1a0632ea078144b2a9063288e937eddb",
            "qrtitle": "this is the one i like.",
            "qid": "269c2de5d3634800a36d64e342b24cba",
            "qkind": "ranking",
            "srid": "26ab2e3f37f642758e03e8aa5a3f373e"
        },
        {
            "qrid": "5d7f9cc459bf4ee8a805c9fccaeabb405d7f9cc459bf4ee8a805c9fccaeabb40.385c5c37a9ce499eafa7e7f162e2cdf6",
            "qrtitle": "this is the one i like.",
            "qid": "269c2de5d3634800a36d64e342b24cba",
            "qkind": "ranking",
            "srid": "1aeb748133f0456785cc87ff33d822d6"
        },
        {
            "qrid": "5d7f9cc459bf4ee8a805c9fccaeabb405d7f9cc459bf4ee8a805c9fccaeabb40.42874d3e33264d9280239464fefd8dbe",
            "qrtitle": "this is the one i like.",
            "qid": "269c2de5d3634800a36d64e342b24cba",
            "qkind": "ranking",
            "srid": "dc84b06e3ee64a60b8e1321be470c16a"
        },
        {
            "qrid": "5d7f9cc459bf4ee8a805c9fccaeabb405d7f9cc459bf4ee8a805c9fccaeabb40.acd93c0cdae3485299912a784dc876bc",
            "qrtitle": "this is the one i like.",
            "qid": "269c2de5d3634800a36d64e342b24cba",
            "qkind": "ranking",
            "srid": "ef7a00ca3f8c4327b51cffd05cf00c8b"
        },
        {
            "qrid": "5d7f9cc459bf4ee8a805c9fccaeabb405d7f9cc459bf4ee8a805c9fccaeabb40.d3a5eb0f0b984cc5862d338a7ad48ce8",
            "qrtitle": "this is the one i like.",
            "qid": "269c2de5d3634800a36d64e342b24cba",
            "qkind": "ranking",
            "srid": "827ee6e3fec0434898e4416b24f166de"
        },
        {
            "qrid": "5d7f9cc459bf4ee8a805c9fccaeabb405d7f9cc459bf4ee8a805c9fccaeabb40.ef995b200a704919a2cab694216baeb0",
            "qrtitle": "this is the one i like.",
            "qid": "269c2de5d3634800a36d64e342b24cba",
            "qkind": "ranking",
            "srid": "1480ce38be4046759e0d2db1a83b7c20"
        }
    ],
    "Wed Jan 10 00:00:00 ICT 2018": [{
            "qrid": "5d7f9cc459bf4ee8a805c9fccaeabb405d7f9cc459bf4ee8a805c9fccaeabb40.042a258ddb99439fa51f0882a467b233",
            "qrtitle": "this is the one i like.",
            "qid": "269c2de5d3634800a36d64e342b24cba",
            "qkind": "ranking",
            "srid": "7dd475e24b8b434895ce732576590bd0"
        },
        {
            "qrid": "5d7f9cc459bf4ee8a805c9fccaeabb405d7f9cc459bf4ee8a805c9fccaeabb40.2171eace203e469583dedf1ea307f3ff",
            "qrtitle": "this is the one i like.",
            "qid": "269c2de5d3634800a36d64e342b24cba",
            "qkind": "ranking",
            "srid": "1a56ea09ca6c457f83f9550b68a70e21"
        },
        {
            "qrid": "5d7f9cc459bf4ee8a805c9fccaeabb405d7f9cc459bf4ee8a805c9fccaeabb40.35311b8ef99e4e9b8128df5b6d6707b1",
            "qrtitle": "this is the one i like.",
            "qid": "269c2de5d3634800a36d64e342b24cba",
            "qkind": "ranking",
            "srid": "dc163ae914594b9a89bcd1151b3a0adc"
        },
        {
            "qrid": "5d7f9cc459bf4ee8a805c9fccaeabb405d7f9cc459bf4ee8a805c9fccaeabb40.455dc78a26294a1a815d68d0dc02bdc5",
            "qrtitle": "this is the one i like.",
            "qid": "269c2de5d3634800a36d64e342b24cba",
            "qkind": "ranking",
            "srid": "a0ab35b7e4b7423ab4fd4b03606f58ba"
        },
        {
            "qrid": "5d7f9cc459bf4ee8a805c9fccaeabb405d7f9cc459bf4ee8a805c9fccaeabb40.5cbf3a30977c49fcb32ce1e086cd4661",
            "qrtitle": "this is the one i like.",
            "qid": "269c2de5d3634800a36d64e342b24cba",
            "qkind": "ranking",
            "srid": "01f28aedaed7481289c37effe4045747"
        },
        {
            "qrid": "5d7f9cc459bf4ee8a805c9fccaeabb405d7f9cc459bf4ee8a805c9fccaeabb40.8429a220b74d40698a1ea39fb46bd5b8",
            "qrtitle": "this is the one i like.",
            "qid": "269c2de5d3634800a36d64e342b24cba",
            "qkind": "ranking",
            "srid": "60e9c74e81ca4650bd0fdd8e30463c76"
        },
        {
            "qrid": "5d7f9cc459bf4ee8a805c9fccaeabb405d7f9cc459bf4ee8a805c9fccaeabb40.8feb181aa884455d81a0f631809e4ffa",
            "qrtitle": "this is the one i like.",
            "qid": "269c2de5d3634800a36d64e342b24cba",
            "qkind": "ranking",
            "srid": "2e529d2b44bc40b7945c2d68b693b057"
        },
        {
            "qrid": "5d7f9cc459bf4ee8a805c9fccaeabb405d7f9cc459bf4ee8a805c9fccaeabb40.a8333465cb744b7f8fd4df3b11c16382",
            "qrtitle": "this is the one i like.",
            "qid": "269c2de5d3634800a36d64e342b24cba",
            "qkind": "ranking",
            "srid": "f1717de12d534298bdca50a431c8087f"
        },
        {
            "qrid": "5d7f9cc459bf4ee8a805c9fccaeabb405d7f9cc459bf4ee8a805c9fccaeabb40.b499dcf69e9646ecbe2495f6153ff14a",
            "qrtitle": "this is the one i like.",
            "qid": "269c2de5d3634800a36d64e342b24cba",
            "qkind": "ranking",
            "srid": "dd0fce71a8fb4036bbb95211d9688463"
        },
        {
            "qrid": "5d7f9cc459bf4ee8a805c9fccaeabb405d7f9cc459bf4ee8a805c9fccaeabb40.b84e2b87fa344bf79436532e626c8593",
            "qrtitle": "this is the one i like.",
            "qid": "269c2de5d3634800a36d64e342b24cba",
            "qkind": "ranking",
            "srid": "457b9af1bb7b4231b4ced51e3e28c7bf"
        },
        {
            "qrid": "5d7f9cc459bf4ee8a805c9fccaeabb405d7f9cc459bf4ee8a805c9fccaeabb40.d0e85c06b55c4882aa4e1000f8365b56",
            "qrtitle": "this is the one i like.",
            "qid": "269c2de5d3634800a36d64e342b24cba",
            "qkind": "ranking",
            "srid": "8c8b858e3dab4b2f92b55904f90ee019"
        },
        {
            "qrid": "5d7f9cc459bf4ee8a805c9fccaeabb405d7f9cc459bf4ee8a805c9fccaeabb40.d38a21324710436fa1b2121a9c12cdbe",
            "qrtitle": "this is the one i like.",
            "qid": "269c2de5d3634800a36d64e342b24cba",
            "qkind": "ranking",
            "srid": "c6776066d8a64d8dbdff18c822216cbd"
        },
        {
            "qrid": "5d7f9cc459bf4ee8a805c9fccaeabb405d7f9cc459bf4ee8a805c9fccaeabb40.d799b85a988c4955b60318d4e7e361a4",
            "qrtitle": "this is the one i like.",
            "qid": "269c2de5d3634800a36d64e342b24cba",
            "qkind": "ranking",
            "srid": "211f1f0977cb4067baca93c13baa4660"
        }
    ]
}
```

This is what appears on running.

[image: Example]

It looks much better than before but there 1 problem still remains. I want to make the lowest bound of the chart (in this case 09-Aug-2017) to move left so the chart series might look like they start from (0,0) coordinate. How can I achieve this?

[image: Desired result]

Comment: Use `setDateFormatOverride()` in a time series chart: [JFreeChart: X Axis contains time stamps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22256756/jfreechart-x-axis-contains-time-stamps)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Let me try if this can solve my problem.

Comment: Hi @CatalinaIsland, the example in the link doesn't help me. I've added my source code above. Please have a look and instruct me what should I do. Thanks.

Comment: Instead of parsing dates, why not `add()` the dates directly to your `TimeSeries`?

Comment: @CatalinaIsland, I've updated my question and my latest source code, and uploaded 2 screenshots as examples of the result. Please have a look and let me know what should I do? Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, without a [mcve] and your sample data, I'm having trouble following. I see your `DateAxis` is working. Have you tried `ChartFactory.createXYLineChart()`?

Comment: Hi @CatalinaIsland, I've modified my question and include both my current source code and my sample data. Please have a look for me. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I'm still confused; it might help to start with `org.jfree.chart.demo.TimeSeriesChartDemo1` for your [mcve]; there should be a copy in your [tag:jfreechart] JAR.

Comment: Hi @CatalinaIsland, I've just changed the last screenshot. Please have a look above. I've already looked at all examples in JFreechart library and in its website but couldn't find anything I need.

Comment: Hi @CatalinaIsland, ok I think I might not explain clearly. What I want is the lowest bound (in this case 09-Aug) to move left so the series may look like they start from (0,0) coordinate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally found the solution. Turns out it's easier than I thought. I added this line

```
dateAxis.setLowerMargin(0);
```

below

```
dateAxis.setLowerBound(0);
```

and before

```
dateAxis.setAutoRange(true);
```

Problem solved.